# Display calendar in month view using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm working on a widget, which among other things opens regular android calendar using intent, upon some user actions.  I'm working on ICS at the moment, so not too concerned with older versions of the API.  I can open the day view with the following code:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent();
intent2.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.AllInOneActivity"));
intent2.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent2.setFlags(0x10200000);
intent2.putExtra("beginTime", dateStartMillis);
intent2.putExtra("VIEW", "DAY");
context.startActivit(intent2);
```

However I can't seem to find a way to open it in month view.  According to [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/calendar/AllInOneActivity.java) for the AllInOneActivity, in its `onCreate` method it calls `Utils.getViewTypeFromIntentAndSharedPref(this);` to determine which view to display.  Here's that method:

```
 public static int getViewTypeFromIntentAndSharedPref(Activity activity) {
     Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     SharedPreferences prefs = GeneralPreferences.getSharedPreferences(activity);

     if (TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_EDIT)) {
         return ViewType.EDIT;
     }
     if (extras != null) {
         if (extras.getBoolean(INTENT_KEY_DETAIL_VIEW, false)) {
             // This is the "detail" view which is either agenda or day view
             return prefs.getInt(GeneralPreferences.KEY_DETAILED_VIEW,
                     GeneralPreferences.DEFAULT_DETAILED_VIEW);
         } else if (INTENT_VALUE_VIEW_TYPE_DAY.equals(extras.getString(INTENT_KEY_VIEW_TYPE))) {
             // Not sure who uses this. This logic came from LaunchActivity
             return ViewType.DAY;
         }
     }

     // Default to the last view
     return prefs.getInt(
             GeneralPreferences.KEY_START_VIEW, GeneralPreferences.DEFAULT_START_VIEW);
 }
```

I don't see in this method (or anywhere else for that matter) a way to set the view to MonthView.  Is there some sort of a trick I can use or should I just accept that this is not possible?

Comment: "I can open the day view with the following code" -- that code is scary. You're one minor update to the Calendar app away from that breaking.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do not disagree, however considering that this is based on an old Android 2.1 code, it's not as bad as it can be.  I wish standard Android calendar provided more ways to launch it to specific views...

Comment: For those stumbling on this post and wondering if there's a better way to open the calendar app on a specific date, I found this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view. Hope this will help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

From here:
[Android Developer Calendar Provider Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view)

Calender Provider offers two different ways to use the VIEW Intent:

To open the Calendar to a particular date.
To view an event.
Here is an example that shows how to open the Calendar to a particular date:

```
// A date-time specified in milliseconds since the epoch.
long startMillis;
...
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is an example that shows how to open an event for viewing:

```
long eventID = 208;
...
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

This also means, that there is no official way to determine which view is shown. Your code only works on that specific calendar app in ICS and wil most probably not work with most other apps.